# How can the Qt Test framework be used for real world projects?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

Coming from other testing frameworks such as Google Test, I'm used to just having all my tests run at the same time with all failed test cases listed together at the bottom. While I managed to find a way to conveniently register all test classes into a single executable project, the test output doesn't seem to be maintainable at all. Each test class run is grouped into a different section in the console output. If you have 100 test classes and a test fails, you quickly end up scrolling to find which test failed. For example, with two test classes I get the following output:

```
********* Start testing of Test_Rule *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.4.2, Qt 5.4.2 (i386-little_endian-ilp32 shared (dynamic) debug build; by GCC 4.9.1)
PASS   : Test_Rule::initTestCase()
FAIL!  : Test_Rule::property_path() Crap
W:/GoogleDrive/Code/Dev/DanWatkins/Testbed/AutoCleaner/Tests/Test_Rule.h(20) : failure location
PASS   : Test_Rule::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 2 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of Test_Rule *********
********* Start testing of Test_AutoCleaner *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.4.2, Qt 5.4.2 (i386-little_endian-ilp32 shared (dynamic) debug build; by GCC 4.9.1)
PASS   : Test_AutoCleaner::initTestCase()
PASS   : Test_AutoCleaner::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of Test_AutoCleaner *********
```

So is there a way to get this output to group each test class into the same "run" call. Ideally the example would look something like this:

```
********* Start testing of EVERYTHING *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.4.2, Qt 5.4.2 (i386-little_endian-ilp32 shared (dynamic) debug build; by GCC 4.9.1)
PASS   : Test_Rule::initTestCase()
PASS   : Test_Rule::cleanupTestCase()

PASS   : Test_AutoCleaner::initTestCase()
PASS   : Test_AutoCleaner::cleanupTestCase()

FAIL!  : Test_Rule::property_path() Crap
W:/GoogleDrive/Code/Dev/DanWatkins/Testbed/AutoCleaner/Tests/Test_Rule.h(20) : failure location
Totals: 4 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of EVERYTHING *********
```

Note I make use of the AutoTest class from [this blog post](http://qtcreator.blogspot.com/2009/10/running-multiple-unit-tests.html). The project is using QMake.

Comment: Are you using QMake?

Comment: Yeah, I am using QMake.